# COMPARING DATA OF DATABASE

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 db and 2 tables EACH

db1

```
TABLE1 TABLE2
1      9
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
```

db2

```
Table3 TABLE 4
2      1
1      2
4      5
3      5
1      9
2      3
```

HOW TO CODE IT IN ASP IF I HAVE TO FIND DB1(1-9) TO DB2(1-9)
(TABLE1="1" = TABLE3="1" AND TABLE2="9" = TABLE 4="9")

HOW CAN I COMPARE THE DATA IN DB1 TO DB2

sorry i'm not good at explaining things, i hope you can help me :(

THANK YOU SO MUCH

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAInl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAInl.png)

Comment: Wow relax with the caps lock... What have you tried so far? You can remove the images as well.

Comment: Can you be more specific with **comparing**? Do you want records that appear in each other or those who do not?

Comment: You have to be more specific with what you mean by 'compare'. What code have you written so far? How is that code not doing what you need it to do?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck.